# Neo4j function "load csv with headers" does not load properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, load-csv

I try to load the following nodes into Neo4j using load CSV with headers command:

```
id  label   name
0   Person  Dave
1   Person  Boris
2   Person  Rita
3   Person  Daniel
4   Person  Papa
5   Person  Mama
```

I save the Excel-Sheet as:

```
CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)
```

and the file location is:

```
 C:\Users\FY197T (2076902)\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\import\nodes.csv
```

Opening in Editor looks like this:

```
id;label;name
0;Person;Dave
1;Person;Boris
2;Person;Rita
3;Person;Daniel
4;Person;Papa
5;Person;Mama
```

To load the nodes into Neo4j I use:

```
load csv with headers from "file:///nodes.csv" as persons create (p1:Person {nodeID:persons.id, label: persons.label, name: persons.name})
```

But what I get is:

```
Added 6 labels, created 6 nodes, completed after 105 ms.
```

So there are 6 nodes (as I have 6 rows), but none of them has any property

I already tried to save the file with different delimiters, or manually adding quotes. Latter gives:

```
there's a field starting with a quote and whereas it ends that quote
there seems to be characters in that field after that ending quote. That 
isn't supported. This is what I read: '"id"";"'
```

PS: I read all the other posts on this topic on stackoverflow, but none solved it yet for me

**EDIT**

1.

```
  load csv with headers from "file:///nodes.csv" as persons FIELDTERMINATOR ';' return persons.label
```

gives:

```
 persons.label
 (empty)
 (empty)
 (empty)
 (empty)
 (empty)
 (empty)
```

2.

```
load csv with headers from "file:///nodes.csv" as persons FIELDTERMINATOR ';' return persons
```

gives:

```
persons
{
   "id": "0",
   "label": "Person",
   "name": "Dave"
}
{
   "id": "1",
  "label": "Person",
   "name": "Boris"
 }
an so on....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with backticks:

```
    load csv with headers from "file:///nodes.csv" as persons FIELDTERMINATOR ';' return persons.`label`;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `;` as the field separator, you should specify the [FIELDTERMINATOR](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-import-data-from-a-csv-file-with-a-custom-field-delimiter) option. This way:

Using this CSV file:

```
id;label;name
0;Person;Dave
1;Person;Boris
2;Person;Rita
3;Person;Daniel
4;Person;Papa
5;Person;Mama
```

And this import script:

```
load csv with headers from "file:///nodes.csv" as persons FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
create (p1:Person {nodeID:persons.id, label: persons.label, name: persons.name})
```

After the import, I ran this simple query over the graph:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

The result as text:

```
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"n"                                            │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"name":"Dave","label":"Person","nodeID":"0"}  │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Boris","label":"Person","nodeID":"1"} │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Rita","label":"Person","nodeID":"2"}  │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Daniel","label":"Person","nodeID":"3"}│
├───────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Papa","label":"Person","nodeID":"4"}  │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"name":"Mama","label":"Person","nodeID":"5"}  │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: unfortunately I get the same result:  Added 6 labels, created 6 nodes

Comment: @Boris very weird... I copied and pasted your CSV data into a file called `nodes.csv` inside the import directory. After added the `FIELDTERMINATOR` option all works... Can you share your raw CSV file that is stored inside the import dir, please?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cnfjhzf9vt2tpj8/nodes.csv?dl=0

Yes very weird, maybe something in the .conf file?

Comment: @Boris, same result with your CSV. All works fine. I'm working over a Linux machine.

Comment: @Boris what is the output of `load csv with headers from "file:///nodes.csv" as persons FIELDTERMINATOR ';' return persons`?

Comment: good idea - now it displays all the properties (see EDIT)
so the issue is with referencing to the headers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152182/discussion-between-bruno-peres-and-boris).